# Syncing Photos.app with external HDD

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, image-editing

I want to have my photo library to sync all the pictures on the HDD, which I can easily reference them by deselecting *"copy items to the photo library"* and import them.

but I want that if I delete the photo in the photos.app, then it would delete the referenced file too. Is that possible?

[image: Preferences in photos app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing without coping to the library doesn't give Photos.app ownership of the file. So to be safe you can't delete it directly from the application. You can right-click on the picture and select **Show related file in Finder** and delete it from there. Unfortunately, it will not delete it from the photo library so you have to do it by yourself.